# How to add a NavigationController to a flipside view?

Tags: iphone, controller, navigation, tableview

I have a flipside view showing the settings in my app. I'm trying to have a few levels of tableViews, but how do I implement a navigation controller to allow this? Usually for a normal root view, the navigation controller is by default in the App Delegate. However how do I do it if the root is the flipside?

Thanks.

Comment: Where to you want to put the info button showing the flipside? In the bar above the table view? Then you could probably show the flipside view as a modal view with the respective animation. I mean then you start with a navigation controller (rather then a flipsideview template)

Comment: OK.. great suggestion. I just did that. But how do I make a call to the app delegate's navigationController from the flipside view? I still have no navigation bar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just create a UINavigationController in the method which displays the flipside. Like so:

```
- (IBAction)showInfo:(id)sender {    

    FlipsideViewController *controller = [[FlipsideViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FlipsideView" bundle:nil];
    controller.delegate = self;

    controller.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;

    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:controller];

    UIBarButtonItem *doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:controller action:@selector(done:)];

    controller.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = doneButton;

    [self presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES];

    [doneButton release];
    [controller release];
    [navController release];
}
```